# alignat introduces extra space with fleqn option

Tags: amsmath, alignat

In my MWE below, there is extra space introduced after the second `=`. How can I get rid of it? I am forced to use the `fleqn` option by my document class:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    X &  = 1XXXXXXXXXX%
    \quad\iff\quad%
    X && = 1XXXXXXXXXXX
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using `alignat` for a single-line formula?

Comment: @AboAmmar: Maybe to make the example code  as minimal as possible…

Comment: @Bernand is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is linked with, on one hand the equation being too long and overflowing into the right margin, and on the other hand,  a not very sensible placement of the 2nd ampersand. With this code, you have no problem:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
    X & = 1XXXXXXXXXX%
&\quad\iff\quad%
    X& = 1XXXXXXXXXXX
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this example, the `&` before the second equals sign isn't needed.  On the other hand, additional lines may make this irrelevant.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: With a single line, no `&` is actually needed.  For  more lines, I have no code from the O.P. to say whatever. I only supposed an alignment on the `=` signs was required – the most usual case, and found out, a little by chance, that this other placement seemed to solve the problem, without explaining it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton my second line would be `\\& = 2&& = 3`, forcing both `=`s to be aligned. With only one `&` in each line, `3` would be forced to the right end of the line.

Comment: @Bernard indeed, splitting the double `&` fixes the problem, thank you. But the underlying issue is indeed a line that is too long, apparent by the equation number reaching into the margin (in my full document at least). Once I fixed that, the double `&` was not a problem anymore. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I also noticed the problem disappeared loading geometry, which defines by default more sensible margins. Note the `fleqn` option does not make equation start at the left margin, but at the  `math margin`(which is \left margin + something).

Comment: @Bernard -- although `geometry` can narrow the margins, giving a wider line for math displays, this is not a possible approach if a document is being submitted for publication in a journal or book series that has a standard trim size, and fixed margins.  While it may look easier for an author, it will either be returned for the displays to be fit inside the allowed margins, or (possibly much worse for the author) be edited by the publisher, with the consequent possibility that errors might be introduced or the meaning changed by an ill-chosen line break.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I only used geometry temporarily to check whether my intuition was correct. The code I posted doesn't load it.

Comment: @Bernard -- The only reason I mentioned `geometry` is that I've had many years of experience with a math publisher, where too many submissions (with excellent subject content) had "solved" the "overfull" problem by adjusting the margins.  Authors need to realize the consequences of this action.